# Why not work back button with android navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-architecture

this my Auth Activity

```
class AuthActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityAuthBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, fragment.id)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)

    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, null)
    }

}
```

LoginFragment -> if login is success goto  "AcceptCodeFragment"

```
 viewModel.loginResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { response ->
            viewBinding.pbLogin.visible(response is Resource.Loading)
            when (response) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    viewBinding.tvResponse.text = response.value.message
                    val action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToAcceptCodeFragment()
                    findNavController().navigate(action)
                }
                is Resource.Error -> if (response.isNetworkError) {
                    requireView().snackBar("Check your connection")
                } else {
                    requireView().snackBar(response.errorBody.toString())
                }
            }
```

in AcceptCodeFragment Back button not work.

Two fragments using same viewmodel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is not with the back button not working, it is that `LiveData` is for **state**, not events like your `loginResponse`. As `LiveData` is for events, it redelivers the previous `response` when you go back to your `LoginFragment`. This then triggers your `navigate()` call again, pushing you right back to your `AcceptCodeFragment`.

As per the [LiveData with SnackBar, Navigation, and other events blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150), `LiveData` cannot be directly used for events. Instead, you should consider using an event wrapper or another solution (such as a Kotlin `Flow`) that allow your events to only be handled once.

Comment: I have 5 days for a hackathon. So I ran into this issue while trying to write code quickly. Since there are 2 fragmentContainers my focus was there. When I saw your answer, I laughed and said, wow, that must be the problem. That was really the problem. Thank you very much for your reply.